# In R, how do I set a value for a variable based on the change from the prior (or following) row?

Tags: r

Given a data frame as follows:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
t<-c(6,8,9,11,12,14,55,57,58,60,62,63)
p<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","b","b","b")
df<-data.frame(id,t,p)

row id  t   p
1   1   6   a
2   1   8   a
3   1   9   a
4   1   11  b
5   1   12  b
6   1   14  b
7   2   55  a
8   2   57  a
9   2   58  b
10  2   60  b
11  2   62  b
12  2   63  b
```

I want to create a new variable 'ta' such that the value of ta is:

1. Zero for the row in which 'p' changes from a to b for a given ID (rows 4 and 9) (this I can do)
2. Within each unique id, when p is 'a', the value of ta should count down from zero by the change in t between the row in question and the row above it.  For example, for row 3, the value of ta should be 0 - (11-9) = -2.
3. Within each unique id, when p is 'b', the value of ta should count up from zero by the change in t between the row in question and the row below it.  For example, for row 5, the value of ta should be 0 + (12-11) = 1.

Thus, when complete, the data frame should look as follows:

```
row id  t   p   ta
1   1   6   a   -5
2   1   8   a   -3
3   1   9   a   -2
4   1   11  b   0
5   1   12  b   1
6   1   14  b   3
7   2   55  a   -3
8   2   57  a   -1
9   2   58  b   0
10  2   60  b   2
11  2   62  b   4
12  2   63  b   5
```

I've been playing around with loops and cumsum() and head() and tail() and can't quite make this kind of within id/within condition summing work.  There are a number of other questions about working with values from previous or following rows, but I can't quite reshape any of those techniques to work here.  Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your algorithm is unclear. How did you get -5 in row 1 and -3 in row 7?

Comment: For row 1, -5 = -3 - (8 - 6).  That is, ta1 = ta2 - (t2-t1).  For row 7, -3 = -1 - (57-55).  That is, ta7 = ta8 - (t8-t7).  Is that more clear?  If not, please let me know and I'll either provide another example or try to structure the question/answer differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. This is a split-apply-combine strategy of breaking everything up by `id`, establishing the transition point between `p=='a'` and `p=='b'` and then subtracting values above and below that. It only works if your data are actually ordered in the way you show them here.

```
do.call('rbind',
lapply(split(df, id), function(x) {
    # save values of `0` at transition points in `p`
    x <- cbind.data.frame(x, ta=ifelse(c(0,diff(as.numeric(as.factor(x$p))))==1, 0, NA))

    # identify indices for those points
    w <- which(x$ta==0)

    # handle `ta` values for `p=='b'`
    x$ta[(w+1):nrow(x)] <- x$ta[w] + (x$t[(w+1):nrow(x)] - x$t[w])

    # handle `ta` values for `p=='a'`
    x$ta[1:(w-1)] <- x$ta[w] - (x$t[w] - x$t[1:(w-1)])

    return(x)
})
)
```

Result:

```
     id  t p ta
1.1   1  6 a -5
1.2   1  8 a -3
1.3   1  9 a -2
1.4   1 11 b  0
1.5   1 12 b  1
1.6   1 14 b  3
2.7   2 55 a -3
2.8   2 57 a -1
2.9   2 58 b  0
2.10  2 60 b  2
2.11  2 62 b  4
2.12  2 63 b  5
```